# Going to bookmark in other window and frame

Tags: frames, bookmarks

I work with two screens (screen 1 and screen 2) and each screen has got an emacs frame (respectively frame 1 and frame 2).
Sometime I have a bookmark in a window in screen 1, the cursor is in screen 2 and I want to jump in the location of the bookmark in screen 1.
If I use bookmark-jump, the current buffer in the current window is replaced with the one containing the bookmark.
If I use bookmark-jump-other-window, in the current frame a new window is created with the buffer contained in screen 1.

So in no case I jump in frame 1 without changing the content of to frame 2.

**I would like to get the following behaviour.**
If the bookmark I want to jump to is not contained in a buffer in any window in any frame, then replace the current buffer in the current window with that one.
If there is a frame containing a buffer with the bookmark, then jump to that frame **without replacing any buffer in the current frame**.

How can I get this behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

This at least gives some of what you request. It does *not*, however, replace the buffer in the selected window. And it is not specific to only bookmarks - it applies to displaying any buffer.  Perhaps it will help.

Just set option `pop-up-frames` to `t`. That will cause every `*-other-window` command to use a separate frame instead of a separate window. If the buffer in question is already open in another frame then its window there is just selected.