# Is there any command like `other-frame` which behaves like windows's Alt-TAB?

Tags: frames

Is there any command like `other-frame` which behaves like windows's Alt-TAB? And how to create this command?

To clarify this behavior, I wrote python code which virtually emulate this behavior. Each elements of `frame_lst` are frames. The first element of the `frame_lst` is the currently selected frame. With `Alt` being pressed, pressing `TAB` N times move the `index` which shows which frame will be selected, and after releasing `TAB` and `Alt` the frame of `index`'th element of `frame_lst` is selected and focused, then change the order of the elements of `frame_lst` to make recently selected frame become first element of the `frame_lst`.

- Emulation Program (virtual_alt_tab.py)

  ```
  def init_environment():
      global frame_lst, index
      index = 0
      frame_lst = ['f1', 'f2', 'f3', 'f4']

  def on_alt_tab_pressed():
      global frame_lst, index
      index += 1
      index = index%len(frame_lst)

  def on_alt_tab_released():
          global frame_lst, index
          frame_lst.insert(0, frame_lst.pop(index))
          index = 0

  def hit_alt_tab_n_times(n):
      global frame_lst
      print('==== Before hitting Alt-TAB ====')
      print(frame_lst)
      for _ in range(n):
          on_alt_tab_pressed()
      on_alt_tab_released()
      print('==== After hitting alt-TAB consecutively %d times ===='%n)
      print(frame_lst)

  # test 1
  print('\n================ test 1 ================')
  init_environment()
  hit_alt_tab_n_times(1)

  # test 2
  print('\n================ test 2 ================')
  init_environment()
  hit_alt_tab_n_times(2)

  # test 3
  print('\n================ test 3 ================')
  init_environment()
  hit_alt_tab_n_times(3)
  ```
- Output

  ```
  ================ test 1 ================
  ==== Before hitting Alt-TAB ====
  ['f1', 'f2', 'f3', 'f4']
  ==== After hitting alt-TAB consecutively 1 times ====
  ['f2', 'f1', 'f3', 'f4']

  ================ test 2 ================
  ==== Before hitting Alt-TAB ====
  ['f1', 'f2', 'f3', 'f4']
  ==== After hitting alt-TAB consecutively 2 times ====
  ['f3', 'f1', 'f2', 'f4']

  ================ test 3 ================
  ==== Before hitting Alt-TAB ====
  ['f1', 'f2', 'f3', 'f4']
  ==== After hitting alt-TAB consecutively 3 times ====
  ['f4', 'f1', 'f2', 'f3']
  ```

I found related article.

https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ControlTABbufferCycling

According to this article Emacs can't detect the release event of the `Alt` key. So I need another mechanics which complement this. I think pressing `C-g` will complement this, but I don't know how to detect `C-g` after `Alt-TAB` pressed repeatedly.

Comment: Please specify the behavior you're looking for, instead of just saying "like window's ALT-TAB". Some of those who might be able to help might not know just what that behavior is or which part(s) of it you're looking for.

Comment: Maybe use `(frame-list)` to get the list of existing frames, and exclude `(selected-frame)` from that, then increment a pointer into that list (as a ring). Use `ring-convert-sequence-to-ring` to convert a list to a ring, then `ring-next` etc.

Comment: @Drew: I added the program which virtually emulate the behavior. But Converting this program to lisp and implement `C-g` detection(see bottom of my question) is long way for me. I almost gave up.

Comment: Sorry, I meant only to please describe MS Windows's ALT-TAB behavior in this context, for people unfamiliar with it. I didn't mean that you needed to show code (e.g. Python) for it.

Comment: @Drew:  It is just writing code is more faster and precise than writing in English in my case. I just write this code in my iPhone while eating my launch. So No need for sorry :)

Answer (score 2):

The function `other-frame`, bound to `C-x 5 o` by default, moves you to the next frame, and calling it repeatedly will cycle you through all available frames. As I recall, that's what `Alt-tab` does?

`ace-window` might also be useful for you. See this answer: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/46587/262

Comment: Yes, `Alt-TAB` cycles frames. I'm currently using Mac and has familiar function(`Command-TAB`). To clarify the behavior I added the program which virtually emulate it. But I almost gave up.